# Having Eclipse Work with jQuery Templates

Tags: jquery, eclipse, jquery-templates

Have alot of the following in this project

> ```
> <script id="placementsListTemplate" type="text/x-query/tmpl">
> ```

Trouble is, Eclipse doesn't see this as html. As it to be expected.

It would sure be nice if this wasn't the case. Is there a way, hacky or no, to make it highlight what is valid HTML as such?

Thanks! :D

Comment: Check out this library as a solution for client-side templating issues like mentioned above https://github.com/leonidas/transparency/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is little far fetched: but if you put templates to a separate file (.html) extension and then use some sort of include mechanism (PHP, Django templates, whatever you are hacking) to grab the actual template to your composed HTML output.

```
<script id="placementsListTemplate" type="text/x-query/tmpl">
{{ include "my.jquery.template.html" }}
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think anyone should ever start modifying his actual code to improve an IDE.

Comment: On the other hand: putting templates inside static HTML is not a good habit either :)

Comment: Upvoting for the good idea but still not a technique I would like to employ. :D

Comment: I have found this library to be an alternative for jQuery templates and it does not have "not seen as HTML" problems https://github.com/leonidas/transparency/